# Warnings with Eigen 3.3.4 after upgrading from GCC 5.4 to GCC 7.2

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen, eigen3

When I compile my code with `-Wall -Werror` using GCC 5.4, it works fine. When I tried it with GCC 7.2 (built from source as native compiler), it gives this:

```
error: enum constant in boolean context [-Werror=int-in-bool-context]
 MayLinearVectorize = bool(MightVectorize) && MayLinearize && DstHasDirectAccess
```

A small example that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    Matrix<double,Dynamic,1> v = Matrix<double,Dynamic,1>::Constant(5, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `g++7 eigtrivial.cpp -I$EIGEN_DIR -Wall -Werror`.

If I try without `-Werror` I get the warnings but it compiles, and all my (few) tests are passing - as far as I can tell it's fine. However, I want to keep all warnings and `-Werror` enabled. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: The warning occurred in Eigen, isn't it? You should report issue to bugzilla...
Workaround: use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored`

Comment: this has been fixed a long time ago in 3.3 and devel branches

Comment: But I just downloaded a fresh copy from the downloads page yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

As ggael said, this has been fixed but is not in an official tarball yet. Cloning from the Mercurial repository (version 3.3.90 as of now) and using that in my code fixed the issue.

Comment: Update: This has been fixed in version 3.3.5 and above.